# How do I provide a custom data as a DataProvider for ImageTilesLayer on a mapControl in XAML file?

Tags: xaml, devexpress, devexpress-wpf

How do I provide a custom data as a DataProvider for ImageTilesLayer on a mapControl in XAML file?

I am new to WPF and DevExpress. I was trying a few examples given in the DevExpress documentation site.

[Link: How to Load Image Tiles from Another Source](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#wpf/CustomDocument11174)

In the example, How to Load Image Tiles from Another Source given in their site, the DataProvider for a ImageTilesLayer is assigned in the code behind file. 
Is it possible to mention the same DataProvider in the XAML instead of the code behind file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign the [ImageTilesLayer.DataProvider](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfMapImageTilesLayer_DataProvidertopic) property in XAML as follows:

```
<dxc:MapControl>
    <dxc:ImageTilesLayer>
        <dxc:ImageTilesLayer.DataProvider>
            <local:CustomMapDataProvider/>
        </dxc:ImageTilesLayer.DataProvider>
    </dxc:ImageTilesLayer>
</dxc:MapControl>
```

P.S.
For more information about XAML properties syntax, see [XAML Overview (WPF)-> Property Element Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752059(v=vs.110).aspx) MSDN article.
For more information about custom types in XAML, see [XAML and Custom Classes for WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753379(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Coding Horror, I would suggest you first read the tutorials given by DevExpress.
Link to the tutorials is below.

https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument10682

It explains the different layers on map control.

Once you have read that, read on how to load images from different source
https://documentation.devexpress.com/#wpf/CustomDocument11174

In the code, instead of giving a url, change it to a local image folder where you have cached all the map tiles.

```
 public class CustomTileSource : MapTileSourceBase {
    const string roadUrlTemplate = 
        @"http://{subdomain}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{tileLevel}/{tileX}/{tileY}.png";
```

You can know more about caching at https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument12205